# "What the...Bitcoin"

Tags: transactions

i'm so new here yall, that I don't yet know what to ask. I'm still researching what the term bitcoin means, and trying to find my 'address', if such a thing exists. Any and all help/comments will be greatly appreciated. TY

Answer (score 0):

A warm welcome to the (sometimes crazy) world of Bitcoin! 
As Nate already pointed out to a link in his comment, all credits go to him. 
Here in stackexchange we are development oriented (not only, but ...), so your starting point would be https://bitcoin.org/en/, and there especially the developper section. 
People do a tremendous fight wether Bitcoin is a currency, or something more like "electronic version of Gold". At the end, it was intended as an "internet money", and it has different flavours of value today. Oh yes, an address exists (usually in your electronic Bitcoin wallet), and is  comparable to an account number of your normal bank. 
Feel free to join the community via https://bitcoin.org/en/, looking forward to see you gaining speed and get involved into this exciting new technology.